# Using Calc with rem in media queries for iPad and iPhone

Tags: html, ios, css, media-queries

The following code works in desktop browsers for Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and IE11.  However, it appears to be ignored by Safari on iPad and iPhone.

I tried adding `only screen` and `max-width` in place of the Level 4 `<` operator.  The cPanel editor has a message of `Unexpected token: calc`.

Can `calc` not be used in Safari? Or is using `rem` an issue?

In Firefox responsive design mode on desktop, the media queries appear to work as desired for small devices.  Even if a user alters the browser default font size to a large value on desktop, the navigation bar will switch from horizontal to vertical as if the desktop was a magnified mobile device.

But it appears to be ignored on iPad and iPhone.

In the head of the HTML there is:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Please let me know what I am overlooking.  Thank you.

```
@media ( width < calc( 42.5rem * 0.625 ) )
 {
   header > div > div
     {
       overflow-y: auto;
       max-height: calc( 100vh - 4.0rem );
       width: 20.0rem;
       margin: 1rem 0;
     }

   nav
    {
     flex-flow: column;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 2.0rem 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the space after the opening `(` and closing `)` - I'm pretty sure that breaks the calculation. Also your value `0.625` does not have a value after it. Be it REM or PX.

Comment: Thanks.  That made no difference.  I don't know what you mean about 0.625 not having a value after it.  It's not supposed to.  At least I don't think so.  It should result in 62.5% of 42.5rem in pixels. At a default font of 16px it yield 425px.